# How to change csv delimiter from "," to " : " in C#

Tags: c#, .net, csv, console-application

I am trying to generate new CSV file from reading a existing CSV file in C# console application.

```
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("C:\\Files\\test_input_file.csv"))
using (FileStream writeStream = File.OpenWrite("C:\\Files\\test_Output_file.csv"))
{
    BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
    BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(writeStream);

    // create a buffer to hold the bytes 
    byte[] buffer = new Byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;

    // while the read method returns bytes
    // keep writing them to the output stream
    while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0)
    {
        writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
```

Now I want to change the delimiter to ":" instead of "," in the output file

How do I do it? Please help me.

Comment: you need to use stream reader not binary reader because of encoding problem. it reads char by char. then simply change `:` char to `,` . note that you also need stream writer.

Comment: I am new to C# .. Can you suggest me where to use stream writer

Answer (score 2):

Because you are trying to modify the text characters then BinaryReader is not a suitable class for your case. due to encoding problem you need to use StreamReader instead.

```
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("C:\\Files\\test_input_file.csv"))
using (FileStream writeStream = File.OpenWrite("C:\\Files\\test_Output_file.csv"))
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(writeStream, reader.CurrentEncoding);

    // create a buffer to hold the chars 
    char[] buffer = new char[1024];
    int charsRead;

    // while the read method returns chars
    // keep writing them to the output stream
    while ((charsRead =
            reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < charsRead; i++)
        {
            if (buffer[i] == ':') buffer[i] = ',';
        }
        writer.Write(buffer, 0, charsRead);
    }
}
```

What is the encoding problem ? a character can be 1, 2 or 3 bytes or even 7 bits etc... depending on encoding. the stream reader will handle this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that:

- your CSV file is encoded in ASCII or UTF-8
- your CSV values will not contain any embedded commas

...you can simply use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
    if (buffer[i] == ',')
        buffer[i] = ':';

writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
```